# Dask Map Tensorflow across Partitions

Tags: tensorflow, dask, dask-distributed

I have a Tensorflow model that I want to run (not train) on my Dask Dataframe. I'm using `map_partitions`. However, when I look at the dashboard to check progress, it is only running 1 task for all of the work . I expected it to process the partitions concurrently. What am I doing wrong?

Start my local cluster:

```
cluster = LocalCluster(ip="0.0.0.0")
client=Client(cluster)

ddf = dd.read_csv("data/docs", names=["docs"])
```

The Dataframes `ddf` is a bunch of sentences (strings) and has 9 partitions.

Here is the TF model:

```
def encode_factory(sess):

    output_tensor_names_sorted = ["input_layer/concat:0"]

    loader.load(sess, 'serve', export_path)

    def encode(sentence):
        #encodes string as `Example` protobuff
        serialized_examples = make_examples(sentence, "word")

        inputs_feed_dict = {"input_example_tensor:0": serialized_examples}

        outputs = sess.run(output_tensor_names_sorted,
                       feed_dict=inputs_feed_dict)
        return outputs[0][0]

    return encode
```

The function `encode_factory` takes a Tensorflow `Session` object and loads the TF model from `export_path` (disk). The function returns a closure which takes a sentence (text string) as input and returns the sentence encoding (embedding/floating point array).

I register it as a future:

```
future_fn = client.scatter(encode_factory, broadcast=True)
```

I then define my mapping function:

```
def map_fn(pdf, encoder):
    #create instance of TF model encoder
    encode = encoder(tf.Session())

    embedded_docs = []

    #iterate through items in Pandas Dataframe
    for doc in pdf.docs:
        doc_embedding = encoder(doc) #pass sentence to TF model
        embedded_docs.append(str(doc_embedding))

    pdf["encoding"] = embedded_docs
    return pdf
```

And apply the map across partitions:

```
ddf.map_partitions(map_fn, future_fn, meta={'docs': str, 'encoding': str}).head()
```

How can I achieve some concurrency, only 1 worker is running!

[image: Dask Dashboard]

Comment: How do you know that only one worker is running?  Are you watching the dashboard, or a system monitor?

Comment: @MRocklin Yes, I mention the dashboard in the 3rd sentence. Does my code look reasonable? I'll post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as I discovered, is quite simple. Since I'm calling `head` as opposed to `compute` I guess Dask only uses 1 worker... If one uses `compute` the tasks are spread across the workers.

Comment: If you are calling `head` then Dask is only looking at a single partition.  It is only able to use as many workers as you have partitions.

Comment: Do you think it's worth leaving this question here for others?

Comment: Yes, I think that you should always leave questions up.

Comment: `ddf.head(npartitions=-1)` will work on the whole data.